# Split a nested python list of dictionaries into 2 dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

So I have nested python list of dicts as follows:

```
{"types": [{ "name": "Chinese", 
             "sub": 
                [{
                   "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}], 
                   "name": "Soups"
                 }, 
                 {
                   "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}], 
                   "name": "Mains"
                 }]
          }]
}
```

What I wanted was to separate out the dicts inside the inner list to finally get this:

```
{"types": [{"name": "Chinese(Soups)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ya", "cost": 1}, {"name": "Ja", "cost": 2}]},

           {"name": "Chinese(Mains)",
            "menu": [{"name": "Ta", "cost": 3}, {"name": "Ba", "cost": 4}]}
          ]
}
```

Some things to be noted are:

- The new **name** key is a combination of inner and outer **name** key
- The **types** key is a list and can have more than 1 element and hence answers should ideally take care of that case

What is the best way of approaching this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you really want this such way, but here you are.

```
{'types': [
    {'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']),
     'menu': inner['menu']}
    for outer in original_dict['types']
    for inner in outer['sub']]}
```

UPD: If you want the original dictionary to be updated, you can do that this way:

```
original_dict['types'] = [
    {'name': '%s(%s)' % (outer['name'], inner['name']),
     'menu': inner['menu']}
    for outer in original_dict['types']
    for inner in outer['sub']]
```

Comment: this creates a new dict altogether..is it possible to do this by making changes to the existing dict ?

Comment: @Amistad, what's the problem with a new dictionary? Do you really need exactly the same dictionary object modified? Personally I would not care about performance or memory issues here, and would just assign the new dictionary to the existing variable: original_dict = {'types': [... in original_dict...]}

Comment: The problem is that this question is a subset of a bigger problem that I am trying to solve.Modifying the existing dict without creating a new one will help in solving the bigger problem quicker..